# Chromium Source Code build seem to be stopped at LINK Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04, chromium

I downloaded the chromium source code using their tools ([as instructed here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code))

and started compiling using the **ninja -C out/Debug chrome**
before that I ran
**./build/gyp_chromium**

It almost took 6 - 7 hours and compiled and now it seems to stuck at **LINK chrome.**

Does this show some kind of error or I should wait more?

I am using ubuntu.

Comment: Is your CPU still spinning and is the RAM usage high? If yes, just wait. Or hit Ctrl+C and try again. 6-7 hours is extremely long, linking a debug build usually takes a few minutes for me... Compiling everything from scratch (including generation of object files) takes less than an hour for me.

Comment: I did Ctrl+C and restarted the computer and tried to run  ninja -C out/Debug chrome  again. Now the situation is more worst. It is saying no package found ninja and blah blah. Did I miss something ?

Comment: Where did you install depot_tools? It must be in your PATH.

Comment: now i installed again ninja-build and ran the above command. now its runing. (it started like this: Warning: bad deps log signature and the on the second line:  [0/16686] ......). in my PATH I didn't get that?  they are in my home folder. By install mean sudo apt-get install ninja-build.